# Installing rvm in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ubuntu, curl

I have trying to install rvm and I found the following message in the terminal after I typed this: ***curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable***

GPG signature verification failed for '/home/ephraim/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.26.3.tgz' - 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/releases/download/1.26.3/1.26.3.tar.gz.asc'!
try downloading the signatures:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
```

or if it fails:

```
command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
```

the key can be compared with:

```
https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc
https://keybase.io/mpapis
```

How can I get rid of these problems?

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: You can use the RVM PPA to get automatic updates: https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm

Answer (score 6):

Follow the instructions in the error and run,

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the signature and import manually.

Get the signature:

```
curl -#LO https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc
```

Import signature:

```
gpg --import mpapis.asc
```

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @rah00l the only answer that fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you may need to run:

> gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3

Note `gpg2`, not `gpg` as mentioned in instruction. Here [more details](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/curl-l-get-rvm-io-bash-s-stable-fails-on-cent-os-on-hostgator) as found. This should be helpful. Make sure you run `gpg` command while logged in as the same OS user who makes rvm installation.